# Find a Lipschitz constant

Tags: analysis, differential

how do I find a Lipschitz constant for $e^{-x^2}$? This is homework so I'd just like some tips on how to proceed. I've got $|e^{-x^2}-e^{-y^2}| = |(e^{-x^2+y^2} -1)||e^{-y^2}| < a$ where $a = -x^2 +y^2$.

I'm not sure how to proceed so any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Thanks that makes sense!

Comment: Can you use the mean value theorem?

Comment: $f(x) = e^{-x^21}$ is differentiable on the whole real line, meaning any $M$ with $M \geq f'(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ will work as a lipschitz constant. As Carsten Schultz already pointed out, you can prove this via the mean value theorem. Write $f(y)$ as $f(x) + \int_{x}^{y} f'(z) dz$, and use $f'(z) \leq M$ plus the mean value theorem to bound the integral.

Comment: @user134919 answer edited

Answer (score 17):

I would solve it like this: you have that $f(x) = e^{-x^2}$. This is the graph of your function:

[image]

As you can see there are two points around $-0.8$ and $0.8$ where the slope is the highest one. The definition of Lipschitz continuous says:

A function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is Lipschitz continuous if there exists some constant L such that:

$$\vert f(x) - f(y)\vert \le L |x-y|$$

Since your $f$ is differentiable, you can use the [mean value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), $$
  \frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x-y} \leq f'(z) \quad\text{for all $x < z < y$,}
$$
and deduce that it is sufficient to find a bound $L$ with $|f'(z)| \leq L$ for all $z \in \mathbb{R}$.

Now from your graph the important thing that you have to understand is if the slope in the points around $-0.8$ and $0.8$ is lower or bigger than $1$ (because there the slope assumes obviously the biggest values). If it's lower than $1$ you can choose $L=1$ and you have $|f(x) - f(y) \le  |x-y|$ because the slope of the function is lower than $1$ and this means that the distance between the images of $f(x)$ is lower than the distance between the arguments in every point $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.

So let's look after the maximal value of the slope of your function $f(x)$ to do that we calculate the derivative of $f(x)$ given by:

$$f'(x) = -2x e^{-x^2}$$

This is the graf of the function $f'(x)$:

[image]

You see that as we said she assumes the maximal values around the points $-0.8$ and $0.8$ to get the exact value we have to derivate once again $f'(x)$ and look for which point the functions is equal to $0$:

$$f''(x) = -2e^{-x^2} + 4x^2e^{-x^2} = e^{-x^2} * (-2 + 4x^2)$$

Now

$$f''(x) = 0 \iff (4x^2 -2) =0$$

since $e^{-x^2}$ will never be $0$

$$\iff x = +\frac{1}{\sqrt(2)} \lor x = -\frac{1}{\sqrt(2)}$$

Now you notice that $f'(\frac{1}{\sqrt(2)}) = -\sqrt{\frac{2}{e}} \gt -1$ and $f'(-\frac{1}{\sqrt(2)}) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{e}} \lt 1$

Now you are allowed to take $L = 1$ and you have your Lipschitz continuity :-)

Comment: Hm, this assumes that one already knows that for differentiable functions, any bound on the derivative works as a lipschitz constant. That's not *immediately* obvious, though - the derivate takes the *limit* of the differential quotient, yet for a lipschitz constant you need a bound on the differential quotient *itself*. But it's not generally true that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n \leq a$ implies $a_n \leq a$ for all $n$...

Comment: Also, you don't usually require your lipschitz constant to be exact, so finding the actual maximum of $f'$ is a bit of overkill. It suffices to find *some* $M$ such that $f'(x) \leq M$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @fgp you are right, you don't need a precise constant $L$ but my $L=1$ was random, you could have taken $L=2$ it is the same, the important thing is that there exists one. Moreover the derivative of a functions is the slope of the functions i.e: $\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$ now if she is $\lt 1$ $\forall x,y$ wouldn't follow automatically that $f(x) - f(y) \lt 1* (x-y)$? maybe I'm wrong ;-) or what did you exactly mean?

Comment: It doesn't really "follow automatically" (at least not for me). $f'(x) \leq 1$ means $\lim_{x\to y} \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} \leq 1$, but the lipschitz condition requires $\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} \leq 1$ **for all** $x,y$. That's, at least initially, a stronger condition! It's entirely conceivable that some differential quotient could be $> 1$, yet the *limit* for $x \to y$ could always end up $\leq 1$. Thus, you need to *prove* that this, indeed, is impossible.

Comment: Your are again right, but since the function $f(x) = e^{-x^2}$ is continuously differentiable this means that the quotient is defined for all x and y and since the quotient takes the maximal values at ${1 \over \sqrt(2)}$ and $-{1 \over \sqrt(2)}$ and there the derivative of $f$ is lower than $1$ than this would be enough, isn't it?

Comment: But you **didn't** show that the quotient takes the maximum value at $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$! That's not even a well-defined statement, since the quotient as *two* parameters - $x$ **and** $y$. What you showed is that the *limit* of the quotient for $x \to y$ has a maximum at $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. That's **not** the same thing. Let me put this differently: For $f(x,y) = |x-y|$, you have $\lim_{x\to y} f(x,y) \leq 0$ for all $y$. Yet there *are* pairs $x,y$ for which $f(x,y) > 0$, e.g. $x=1,y=0$.

Comment: You are right again, but the fact that the limit of the quotient takes his maximal values at ${1 \over \sqrt(2)}$ implies that there is not "path" on the function that has a slope greater than $\sqrt{{2\over e}}$ because otherwise we would have found another point with greater slope on the function f.

Comment: Oh, and BTW, you mixed up the signs in the line "Now you notice that.... First, $f'(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$ should be negative, and $f'(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$ should be positive (as per your plot ;-)). And second, the $<$ in $-\sqrt{\frac{2}{e}} < -1$ should be a $>$...

Comment: Again, no. The slope is a *local* property - it's the slope at *one* particular point. The differential quotient allows arbitrary pairs of $x$ and $y$. You have to bridge that gap somehow. I don't really know what you mean by "path on the function", but I assume you mean that geometric intuition tells you that the derivative does, indeed, bound the slope of *arbitrary* lines drawn between *two* points on the function's graph. Which is indeed true, but geometric intuition doesn't constitute a proof!

Comment: @fgp Look [here](http://people.bath.ac.uk/rm257/MA30041/chapter4.pdf) at example 4.1.1 what I mean ;)

Comment: Exactly. That example 4.1.1 *proves* what you have simply assumed without stating it explictily. That was what I criticized - not that your answer was wrong (it isn't), but that it was *incomplete*. BTW, I'm going to edit your answer and put the proof in there, instead of referencing it - it's only a few lines....

Comment: How does the inequality arise in the mean values thereom statement, the one with z